# Bottle Microframework does not close the socket once is closed

Tags: python, sockets, rest, popen, bottle

I ran an API RestFul with bottle and python, all works fine, the API is a daemon running in the system, if I stop the daemon by command line the service stop very well and closed all the port and connections, but when I go to close the service through the API, the port keep alive in state LISTEN and later in TIME_WAIT, it does not liberate the port. I've read for two days but the problem is because bottle have a socket and it does not close the server well, but I can find he solution

The code to close the API as a service is a subprocess launched by python like this

```
@get('/v1.0/services/<id_service>/restart')
def restart_service(id_service):
try:
    service = __find_a_specific_service(id_service)
    if(service == None or len(service) < 1):
        logging.warning("RESTful URI: /v1.0/services/<id_service>/restart " +    id_service +" , restart a specific service, service does not exists")
        response.status = utils.CODE_404
        return utils.convert_to_json(utils.FAILURE, utils.create_failed_resource(utils.WARNING, utils.SERVICES_API_SERVICE_NOT_EXIST))
    else:
        if id_service != "API":
            api.ServiceApi().restart(id_service)
        else:
            import subprocess                
            args='/var/lib/stackops-head/bin/apirestd stop; sleep 5; /var/lib/stackops-head/bin/apirestd start'
            subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
        logging.info("RESTful URI: /v1.0/services/<id_service>/restart " + id_service +" , restart a specific service, ready to construct json response...")
        return utils.convert_to_json(utils.SERVICE, None)
except Exception, e:
    logging.error("Services: Error during the process of restart a specific service. %r", e)
    raise HTTPError(code=utils.CODE_500, output=e.message, exception=e, traceback=None, head
```

Answer (score 1):

To terminate a bottle process from the outside, send SIGINT.

Answer (score 1):

If app is exited or killed, all file descriptors/handles also including socket are closed by OS.

You can also use

```
sudo netstat -anp --tcp
```

in Linux to make sure if the specified port is owned by some processes. Or use

```
netstat -a -n -b -p tcp
```

in Windows to do the same thing.

TIME_WAIT is normal state managed by OS rather than app to keep a connection/port for a while. Sometimes it is annoying. Your can tune OS for how long it will keep, but it is not safe.